# How to use Angular - post form data to rest api

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How is it possible to post form data to an external rest API?

At the moment I have an HTML form:

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid fixed>
    <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center nowrap>
      <ion-col col-auto>
        <h2 text-capitalize>quick order</h2>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <form #formQuickOrder="ngForm">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let inputElem of templateData">
            <!-- <ng-container *ngFor="let inputElem of templateData"> -->
              <ion-label color="primary" floating>
                <ion-icon name="{{inputElem.icon}}"></ion-icon>
                <ion-note text-capitalize>{{inputElem.label}}</ion-note>
              </ion-label>

              <ion-input *ngIf="inputElem.name == 'name' else F" #input (ionBlur)="onInputBlur(input)" [type]="inputElem.type" name="inputElem.name" [(ngModel)]="inputElem.model" ngModel required minLength="3" maxLength="50"></ion-input>
              <ng-template #F><ion-input #input (ionBlur)="onInputBlur(input)" [type]="inputElem.type" name="inputElem.name" [(ngModel)]="inputElem.model" ngModel required></ion-input></ng-template>
              <!-- <span *ngIf="!input.ngControl.valid && isSentOrderClicked">{{input.getNativeElement().children[0].validationMessage}}</span> -->
            <!-- </ng-container> -->
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list> 
        </form>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <div class="btn-holder">
    <button (click)="onOrder()" class="btn-order-now" ion-button color="dark" outline round>order now</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

and then I have the function that is handling the submit in my component.ts file:

```ts
onOrder(formQuickOrder: NgForm) {
    console.log(formQuickOrder)

    //this.http.post('http://xxx/externalapi/add', formQuickOrder);
}
```

But how is it possible to post the form data to my external API? And what is the standard of sending form data with angular? Is it just a simple post request with form data as queryParams or is it standard to convert it into JSON. I can modify the API to handle whatever data is sent so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular [**HttpClient**](https://angular.io/guide/http) and using it's **POST** method you can send your data to the backned.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

pubic onOrder(formQuickOrder: NgForm): void {
    this.postData(pass your form value here);
}

priavte postData (formData: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(this.yourUrl, formData);
}
```

Comment: What is the output of console log(formQuickOrder)?

Comment: Check the html one

Comment: You can get the value of the form using **formQuickOrder.value** right?
Then you can directly pass that data to http.post method.
What happens when you post your form data?

Comment: Update your question with the errors that you are grtting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171439/discussion-between-anuradha-gunasekara-and-dr-tz).